# Finding a PowerPoint shape using Alternative text without looping through all shapes in C#

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

Is there any way to get a shape without looping through all shapes in a slide? I am currently looping through shapes and identifying the shape with its Alternative text.

```
    foreach (PowerPoint.Shape objShape in objShapes)
    {
        if(objShape.AlternativeText.CompareTo("ObjAltText").ToString()==0)
            //add code 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each shape has a .Name property that's somewhat but not perfectly reliable.

Shapes also have unique .ID property that never changes.

Assuming you know the value of either ahead of time, you can directly return a reference to the shape.

Shapes (and slides and presentations) can also have a .Tags property that returns a collection of .Tag objects, each a key/value pair.  If you don't mind looping thorough the shapes collection (and it can be VERY fast, so why not?) you can look for the shape with the tag you've assigned it.

Or the slide could have a tag that points to the name of the shape you're after.